# Blender give black video after using ffmpeg -codec copy to trim it

Tags: video, blender

I'm working on a project in Blender 2.69.  I added all of the video files up front. I later decided I wanted to manipulate a video file in another program and re-add it.  When I re-added it, Blender showed black/blank frames in the Video Sequence Editor Preview. In the Video Sequence Editor Preview's properties under "View Settings" I've set "Proxy rend" to "Proxy size 25%" to speed up previews. Did my other program somehow write a video file that Blender could partially read?  What's going wrong?

Comment: Please rather show the full output log from your copying command than the individual input/output logs.

Comment: My question has been massively overhauled. I originally thought my "another program" (ffmpeg) was generating files Blender had problems with, and included a great deal of log output that turned out to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other program is a red herring.  Blender is perfectly happy with the modified video file. The important bit is " In the Video Sequence Editor Preview's properties under 'View Settings' I've set 'Proxy rend' to 'Proxy size 25%' to speed up previews." Once you're done that, you need to create proxies for your video files.

When I added the original video files, I opened the properties for each strip and checked "Proxy / Timecode" and "25" (for 25%).  When I added the additional file I forgot that I needed to check those options *and* run Strip > Rebuild Proxy and Timecode Indices. Once I did that, it worked as expected.